# How to load migration library without specifying database? (Code Igniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

I am new to code igniter. After playing around with the MVC model, I want to find a way to create and setup database, and the migration class seems to be useful after reading the menu.

So I decided to give it a try by first loading the library by changing the line in autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','migration');
```

So, before building anything else, I go to the default welcome page again to make sure I am doing the correct thing. Then....

```
Error Number: 1102

Incorrect database name ''

SHOW TABLES FROM ``

Filename: libraries/Migration.php

Line Number: 72
```

I am going to create the database in my migration script, so of course the initial database will be blank at the beginning.... I guess the default welcome page don't need a database, right?

So I tried changing the settings to the database I will be creating, changing the line in database.php:

```
$db['default']['database'] = 'testingdb';
```

Then, the error message changes to:

```
Unable to select the specified database: testingdb

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

So I guess it is the problem of auto loading, and move the loading function to the migration controller, like what taught in the official tutorial.

```
class Migrate extends CI_Controller{
function index(){
    $this->load->library('migration');
    if ( ! $this->migration->current())
    {
        show_error($this->migration->error_string());
    }
}
}
```

So the default welcome page is okay, but crash when I am running the migration script, with the same error message as the one I shown at the beginning.

So, I must create a database before I can do any migration? Or did I missed anything?

(Sigh.... Didn't expect loading the migration library will crash the default welcome page....)